# How do I control the network resources added when creating Azure Container Environment using Terraform

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

If I was to use this example to create an Azure Container Environment and Apps via Terraform...

```
##################### Resource Group #####################

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
  tags     = var.tags
}


##################### Workspace #####################

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "law" {
  name                = var.workspace_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 90
  tags                = var.tags
}


##################### Network #####################

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "network" {
  name                = var.virtual_network_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  tags                = var.tags

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rg
  ]
}


##################### Subnet #####################

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = var.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name

  address_prefixes = ["10.0.0.0/23"]

  service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB", "Microsoft.Storage"]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rg,
    azurerm_virtual_network.network
  ]
}


##################### Container App Environment #####################

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "cae" {
  name                           = var.cae_name
  location                       = var.location
  resource_group_name            = var.resource_group_name
  log_analytics_workspace_id     = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.id
  infrastructure_subnet_id       = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
  internal_load_balancer_enabled = false
  tags                           = var.tags

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rg,
    azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law,
    azurerm_subnet.subnet
  ]
}
```

I would find some additional resources created in a new resource group with a random name:
[image: New Resources]

My question is, can we use Terraform to create those so that I can put them in the same resource group and control their names, tags etc.

Comment: Are you planning to create resources in Azure Container Environment and Apps using your own naming conventions?

Comment: Yes thats right. The example in the link shows how I would use Terraform to create the env and apps, but not how I would create the network resources

Comment: Do you want to create Public IP, NSG and Load Balancer along with **Azure Container Environment** and **Apps** using only modules or any module like azurerm?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for an example that explicitly creates the env, apps and network recourses. The example in my question only creates the env and apps

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy resources in Azure using Terraform, Azure sometimes creates additional, ancillary resources to support the primary resource. These automatically generated resources usually come with auto-generated names.

Some Azure resources inherently depend on other resources. For example, when you create a Virtual Machine, Azure might create additional resources like a Network Interface Card (NIC) if you don’t specify an existing one.

To avoid surprises, I always,  Before applying any changes, run terraform plan. This will show you all the resources Terraform intends to create, modify, or destroy. This is a good chance to catch unexpected resources.

If there are resources you find being created automatically and you want to define and control them via Terraform, you can:

```
1.  Look for the corresponding Terraform resource in the Terraform Azure Provider documentation.
2.  Define the resource explicitly in your Terraform code.
3.  Link the resource to its parent/dependent resource as necessary.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. In this case these extra resources are not shown in the plan. Even if it were, I can't see anything in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/container_app_environment) that would allow me to assign these resources to the app env

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, can we use Terraform to create those so that I can apply naming conventions, tags etc.

To create resources with your `own naming conventions`, below is the `Terraform code`

```
name ="${var.resource_prefix}-${var.blob_private_endpoint}"
```

`${var.resource_prefix}"` is a constant value used for all resources.
`"${var.blob_private_endpoint}"` allows you to define a custom resource name at the time of input.

For example, if **"resource_prefix"** is set to "Prod" and **"blob_private_endpoint"** is set to **"demoendpoint,"** the resource name is created as follows: **[resource_prefix]-demoendpoint**

```
 prod-demoendpoint
```

Kindly follow the same format in all resources.

**Terraform Plan:**

[image]

Here is terraform code to create **Azure Container Environment** and **Apps** with network resources using own naming convention.

```json
 terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.3"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.43.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

resource "random_string" "resource_prefix" {
  length  = 6
  special = false
  upper   = false
  numeric  = false
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "venkattests-resources"
}

module "log_analytics_workspace" {
  source                           = "./modules/log_analytics"
  name                             = "log-${var.resource_prefix}-${var.log_analytics_workspace_name}"
  location                         = var.location
  resource_group_name              = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

module "application_insights" {
  source                           = "./modules/application_insights"
  name                             = "${var.resource_prefix}-${var.application_insights_name}"
  location                         = var.location
  resource_group_name              = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  application_type                 = var.application_insights_application_type
  workspace_id                     = module.log_analytics_workspace.id
  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

module "virtual_network" {
  source                           = "./modules/virtual_network"
  resource_group_name              = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  vnet_name                        = "${var.resource_prefix}-${var.virtual_network}"
  location                         = var.location
  address_space                    = var.vnet_address_space
  log_analytics_workspace_id       = module.log_analytics_workspace.id
  log_analytics_retention_days     = var.log_analytics_retention_days
  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }

  subnets = [
    {
      name : var.aca_subnet_name
      address_prefixes : var.aca_subnet_address_prefix
      private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled : true
      private_link_service_network_policies_enabled : false
    },
    {
      name : var.private_endpoint_subnet_name
      address_prefixes : var.private_endpoint_subnet_address_prefix
      private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled : true
      private_link_service_network_policies_enabled : false
    }
  ]
}

module "blob_private_dns_zone" {
  source                       = "./modules/private_dns_zone"
  name                         = "${var.resource_prefix}-${var.blob_private_dns_zone}"
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_networks_to_link     = {
    (module.virtual_network.name) = {
      subscription_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    }
  }
}

module "network-security-group" {
  source                = "Azure/network-security-group/azurerm"
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location              = "EastUS" # Optional; if not provided, will use Resource Group location
  security_group_name   = "${var.resource_prefix}-${var.network-security-group}"
  source_address_prefix = ["10.0.3.0/24"]
  predefined_rules = [
    {
      name     = "SSH"
      priority = "500"
    },
    {
      name              = "LDAP"
      source_port_range = "1024-1026"
    }
  ]

  custom_rules = [
    {
      name                   = "myssh"
      priority               = 201
      direction              = "Inbound"
      access                 = "Allow"
      protocol               = "Tcp"
      source_port_range      = "*"
      destination_port_range = "22"
      source_address_prefix  = "10.151.0.0/24"
      description            = "description-myssh"
    },
    {
      name                    = "myhttp"
      priority                = 200
      direction               = "Inbound"
      access                  = "Allow"
      protocol                = "Tcp"
      source_port_range       = "*"
      destination_port_range  = "8080"
      source_address_prefixes = ["10.151.0.0/24", "10.151.1.0/24"]
      description             = "description-http"
    },
  ]

  tags = {
    environment = "dev"
    costcenter  = "it"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "${var.resource_prefix}-${var.azurerm_public_ip}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 30

  tags = {
    environment = "test"
  }
}

module "mylb" {
  source              = "Azure/loadbalancer/azurerm"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  prefix              = "terraform-test"

  remote_port = {
    ssh = ["Tcp", "22"]
  }

  lb_port = {
    http = ["80", "Tcp", "80"]
  }

  lb_probe = {
    http = ["Tcp", "80", ""]
  }

}
module "blob_private_endpoint" {
  source                         = "./modules/private_endpoint"
  name                           = "${var.resource_prefix}-${var.blob_private_endpoint}"
  location                       = var.location
  resource_group_name            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  subnet_id                      = module.virtual_network.subnet_ids[var.private_endpoint_subnet_name]
  private_connection_resource_id = module.storage_account.id
  is_manual_connection           = false
  subresource_name               = "blob"
  private_dns_zone_group_name    = "BlobPrivateDnsZoneGroup"
  private_dns_zone_group_ids     = [module.blob_private_dns_zone.id]
  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

module "storage_account" {
  source                           = "./modules/storage_account"
  name                             = "${var.storage_account}"
  location                         = var.location
  resource_group_name              = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  account_kind                     = var.storage_account_kind
  account_tier                     = var.storage_account_tier
  replication_type                 = var.storage_account_replication_type
  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

module "container_apps" {
  source                           = "./modules/container_apps"
  managed_environment_name         = "container-${var.resource_prefix}"
  location                         = var.location
  resource_group_name              = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  infrastructure_subnet_id         = module.virtual_network.subnet_ids[var.aca_subnet_name] 
  instrumentation_key              = module.application_insights.instrumentation_key
  workspace_id                     = module.log_analytics_workspace.id
  dapr_components                  = [{
                                      name            = var.dapr_name
                                      component_type  = var.dapr_component_type
                                      version         = var.dapr_version
                                      ignore_errors   = var.dapr_ignore_errors
                                      init_timeout    = var.dapr_init_timeout
                                      secret          = [
                                        {
                                          name        = "storageaccountkey"
                                          value       = module.storage_account.primary_access_key
                                        }
                                      ]
                                      metadata: [
                                        {
                                          name        = "accountName"
                                          value       = module.storage_account.name
                                        },
                                        {
                                          name        = "containerName"
                                          value       = var.container_name
                                        },
                                        {
                                          name        = "accountKey"
                                          secret_name = "storageaccountkey"
                                        }
                                      ]
                                      scopes          = var.dapr_scopes
                                     }]
 container_apps                   = var.container_apps
}
```

**Varaible.tf**

```
variable "resource_prefix" {
  description = "Specifies a prefix for all the resource names."
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "(Required) Specifies the supported Azure location where the resource exists. Changing this forces a new resource to be created."
  type        = string
  default     = "WestEurope"
}

variable "blob_private_dns_zone" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the log analytics workspace"
  type        = string
}
variable "azurerm_public_ip" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the log analytics workspace"
  type        = string
}

variable "blob_private_endpoint" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the log analytics workspace"
  type        = string
}

variable "storage_account" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the log analytics workspace"
  type        = string
}


variable "network-security-group" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the log analytics workspace"
  type        = string
}
variable "log_analytics_workspace_name" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the log analytics workspace"
  type        = string
}

variable "log_analytics_retention_days" {
  description = "Specifies the number of days of the retention policy for the log analytics workspace."
  type        = number
  default     = 30
}

variable "application_insights_name" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the application insights resource."
  type        = string
}

variable "application_insights_application_type" {
  description = "(Required) Specifies the type of Application Insights to create. Valid values are ios for iOS, java for Java web, MobileCenter for App Center, Node.JS for Node.js, other for General, phone for Windows Phone, store for Windows Store and web for ASP.NET. Please note these values are case sensitive; unmatched values are treated as ASP.NET by Azure. Changing this forces a new resource to be created."
  type        = string
  default     = "web"
}

variable "virtual_network" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the virtual network"
  type        = string
}

variable "vnet_address_space" {
  description = "Specifies the address prefix of the virtual network"
  default     =  ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "aca_subnet_name" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the subnet"
  type        = string
}

variable "aca_subnet_address_prefix" {
  description = "Specifies the address prefix of the Azure Container Apps environment subnet"
  default     = ["10.0.0.0/20"]
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "private_endpoint_subnet_name" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the subnet"
  type        = string
}

variable "private_endpoint_subnet_address_prefix" {
  description = "Specifies the address prefix of the private endpoints subnet"
  default     = ["10.0.16.0/24"]
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "storage_account_name" {
  description = "(Optional) Specifies the name of the storage account"
  type        = string
}

variable "storage_account_replication_type" {
  description = "(Optional) Specifies the replication type of the storage account"
  default     = "LRS"
  type        = string

  validation {
    condition = contains(["LRS", "ZRS", "GRS", "GZRS", "RA-GRS", "RA-GZRS"], var.storage_account_replication_type)
    error_message = "The replication type of the storage account is invalid."
  }
}

variable "storage_account_kind" {
  description = "(Optional) Specifies the account kind of the storage account"
  default     = "StorageV2"
  type        = string

   validation {
    condition = contains(["Storage", "StorageV2"], var.storage_account_kind)
    error_message = "The account kind of the storage account is invalid."
  }
}

variable "storage_account_tier" {
  description = "(Optional) Specifies the account tier of the storage account"
  default     = "Standard"
  type        = string

   validation {
    condition = contains(["Standard", "Premium"], var.storage_account_tier)
    error_message = "The account tier of the storage account is invalid."
  }
}

variable "managed_environment_name" {
  description = "(Required) Specifies the name of the managed environment."
  type        = string
}

variable "internal_load_balancer_enabled" {
  description = "(Optional) Should the Container Environment operate in Internal Load Balancing Mode? Defaults to false. Changing this forces a new resource to be created."
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

variable "dapr_name" {
  description = "(Required) Specifies the name of the dapr component."
  type        = string
  default     = "statestore"
}

variable "dapr_component_type" {
  description = "(Required) Specifies the type of the dapr component."
  type        = string
  default     = "state.azure.blobstorage"
}

variable "dapr_ignore_errors" {
  description = "(Required) Specifies  if the component errors are ignored."
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

variable "dapr_version" {
  description = "(Required) Specifies the version of the dapr component."
  type        = string
  default     = "v1"
}

variable "dapr_init_timeout" {
  description = "(Required) Specifies the init timeout of the dapr component."
  type        = string
  default     = "5s"
}

variable "dapr_scopes" {
  description = "(Required) Specifies the init timeout of the dapr component."
  type        = list
  default     = ["nodeapp"]
}

variable "container_name" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the container in the storage account."
  type        = string
  default     = "state"
}

variable "container_access_type" {
  description = "Specifies the access type of the container in the storage account."
  type        = string
  default     = "private"
}

variable "container_apps" {
  description = "Specifies the container apps in the managed environment."
  type = list(object({
    name                           = string
    revision_mode                  = optional(string)
    ingress                        = optional(object({
      allow_insecure_connections   = optional(bool)
      external_enabled             = optional(bool)
      target_port                  = optional(number)
      transport                    = optional(string)
      traffic_weight               = optional(list(object({
        label                      = optional(string)
        latest_revision            = optional(bool)
        revision_suffix            = optional(string)
        percentage                 = optional(number)
      })))
    }))
    dapr                           = optional(object({
      app_id                       = optional(string)
      app_port                     = optional(number)
      app_protocol                 = optional(string)
    }))
    secrets                        = optional(list(object({
      name                         = string
      value                        = string
    })))
    template                       = object({
      containers                   = list(object({
        name                       = string
        image                      = string
        args                       = optional(list(string))
        command                    = optional(list(string))
        cpu                        = optional(number)
        memory                     = optional(string)
        env                        = optional(list(object({
          name                     = string
          secret_name              = optional(string)
          value                    = optional(string)
        })))
      }))
      min_replicas                 = optional(number)
      max_replicas                 = optional(number)
      revision_suffix              = optional(string)
      volume                       = optional(list(object({
        name                       = string
        storage_name               = optional(string)
        storage_type               = optional(string)
      })))
    })
  }))
  default                          = [{
    name                           = "nodeapp"
    revision_mode                  = "Single"
    ingress                        = {
      external_enabled             = false
      target_port                  = 3000
      transport                    = "http"
      traffic_weight               = [{
        label                      = "blue"
        latest_revision            = true
        revision_suffix            = "blue"
        percentage                 = 100
      }]
    }
    dapr                           = {
      app_id                       = "nodeapp"
      app_port                     = 3000
      app_protocol                 = "http"
    }
    template                       = {
      containers                   = [{
        name                       = "hello-k8s-node"
        image                      = "dapriosamples/hello-k8s-node:latest"
        cpu                        = 0.5
        memory                     = "1Gi"
        env                        = [{
          name                     = "APP_PORT"
          value                    = 3000
        }]
      }]
      min_replicas                 = 1
      max_replicas                 = 1
    }
  },
  {
    name                           = "pythonapp"
    revision_mode                  = "Single"
    dapr                           = {
      app_id                       = "pythonapp"
      app_port                     = 80
    }
    template                       = {
      containers                   = [{
        name                       = "hello-k8s-python"
        image                      = "dapriosamples/hello-k8s-python:latest"
        cpu                        = 0.5
        memory                     = "1Gi"
      }]
      min_replicas                 = 1
      max_replicas                 = 1
    }
  }]
}
```

`Resources` are created in portal with my own naming convention, as below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very details answer. Jut out of curiously, what was the value or the FQDN or Application Url for the container app in your example?

Comment: In my case, I have given a random name to my container app in a variable.

Comment: could you share the code for the **./modules/private_dns_zone**, **Azure/loadbalancer/azurerm** and **Azure/network-security-group/azurerm** modules please?